# Prove that a continuous function of compact support defined on $R^n$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am working through a few sets of notes I found on the internet and I came across this exercise. How do I prove that a continuous function $f$ of compact support defined on $R^n$ is bounded?

It seems believable that it is true for $f$ in $R$ because I can visualize it but how do I prove this properly for $R^n$? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know that the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Is the image just the set of all values that the function can take? If so, then all that is required for this exercise is to state what you stated and then say that the image is compact and therefore bounded (and closed)? If so, then it seems a really short exercise and I guess I was way overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Put $K = {\rm supp}(|f|)$.  Since $K$ is compact and $|f|$ is continuous, then $\sup_{K} |f| < \infty$ and the supremum is attained on $K$.  Since $f$ is zero off $K$, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be the support of $f$. Since the image of a compact set through a continuous function is compact, $f(K)$ is closed and bounded by the [Heine-Borel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem).